# R combine rColorRamp & Transparency

Tags: r

I'm new to R, and I've written the below to create a plot where the points are coloured based on a third variable, on a scale from the color ramp going red/yellow/green. It works fine, but I have several points that overlap so the final plot is not as clear as I'd like. Is there a way to use colorramp with semi-transparent colours?

```
col<- colorRampPalette(c("#d62728", "#fbee29","#2ca02c"))
sto.col <- col(100)

plot(agg.ASP$OTB.Qty,agg.ASP$ASP, type="n")
for (i in 1:length(agg.ASP$STO)) {
  col.index <- agg.ASP$STO[i] * 100
  points(agg.ASP$OTB.Qty[i], agg.ASP$ASP[i], col=sto.col[col.index], pch=16)
}
```

Comment: `sto.col = paste0(col(100), "33")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `colorRampPalette()` function (`col`) returns hex color codes; you can just append 2 additional characters signifying opacity to the result of this; For example, I just change 1 line in your code (replace '33' here with the level of transparency you want):

```
col<- colorRampPalette(c("#d62728", "#fbee29","#2ca02c"))
sto.col = paste0(col(100), "33")

plot(agg.ASP$OTB.Qty,agg.ASP$ASP, type="n")
for (i in 1:length(agg.ASP$STO)) {
  col.index <- agg.ASP$STO[i] * 100
  points(agg.ASP$OTB.Qty[i], agg.ASP$ASP[i], col=sto.col[col.index], pch=16)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
colorRampPalette(c("#d6272833", "#fbee2933","#2ca02c33"), alpha=TRUE)
```